# How does $\text{Cov}(\varepsilon_i , \varepsilon_j ) = 0$ imply that $\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) = 0$?

Tags: statistics, regression, covariance

Not sure where to start here.

A few things I know:

$$ E(Y_i) = E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i)$$

$$   E(Y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + E(\epsilon_i) $$

$$   E(Y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i\,,$$ since  $  E(\epsilon_i) = 0 $.

Then using the definition of Covariance in terms of expectation,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(Y_i, Y_j)&= E(Y_iY_j) - E(Y_i)E(Y_j)
\\&= E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i,\beta_0 + \beta_1X_j + \epsilon_j ) - E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i)E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_j + \epsilon_j) 
\\&= E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i,\beta_0 + \beta_1X_j + \epsilon_j ) - (\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i)(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_j + \epsilon_j) 
\end{align}

Not sure what to do from here. I don't know if this the right of wrong way to do this proof. Am I missing a an important assumption to finish this proof?

Comment: Could you detail all the assumptions? e.g. $X_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are independent

Comment: @Pebeto for all  $i \neq j$ ,$Y_i and Y_j$  are assumed to be uncorrelated as well as $\epsilon_i and \epsilon_j$ are assumed to be uncorrelated

Comment: Are you sure about $Y_i & Y_j$ uncorrelated? This is your conclusion

Comment: If the $X_i$ are considered non random then yes this conclusion would be correct.

Comment: @Pebeto sorry, you're right that is our conclusion

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the covariance operator invarianet under shifting, that is 
$$
Cov(a+X, c + Y) = Cov(X,Y).
$$
Thus if you assume that $X_i$ are constants, you have that
$$
Cov(Y_i, Y_j) = Cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j)=0.  
$$